# Is it possible to create Go Ascii Text (GoAT) diagrams with colors?

Tags: go, markdown, diagram, hugo

I am new to HUGO/GO and found that GoAT diagrams are natively supported. This is an amazing tool to convert my markdown text to black & white block diagrams, like this: [image]
But my requirement is to have such diagrams with colored lines and blocks, like: [image]

So, any suggestions on how can I achieve this?

NOTE: HUGO also supports Mermaid diagrams (https://gohugo.io/content-management/diagrams/#goat-diagrams-ascii), which supports themes, but that does not support Swimlanes and nested blocks diagrams like GoAT simply does.

Comment: As far as I can see, the GoAT library currently does not support colors in its SVG output. As you pointed out, Mermaid is also not an option for this particular use case. Since Hugo only recognizes these two types of diagrams, we have two potential solutions: Either GoAT should be extended to support colors, or the SVG produced by GoAT needs to be modified accordingly. However, modifying the SVG raises another question. Due to the complexity of the issue, I believe it's best to close this question, as it may be too broad for the format of StackOverflow. The question is nevertheless interesting